# Encrypt data without special character ("=")

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have written simple encryption and decryption program in java. And I am using `"AES" algorithm` for encryption and decryption.
It is working fine, but in encrypted data I am getting special characters like `"/","="` etc.

But I don't want the special characters in encrypted data specially "=" operator. Because it causing issue for my further processing.
Is there any way to avoid special characters or single `"="` operator in encrypted data.

I googled it and I got some suggestion like, convert the data into hashcode, so hashcode encryption will not contains special character.
But as per the suggestions, hashcode encryption is not `secret key` based, I needed the encryption using `secret key`

How can I achive this?

Any help will appriciated.
Thanks

Following is program I have written in java:

```
public class EncDec
{
    private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = "1234567891234567".getBytes();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        String testData = "ABC";
        String enc = encrypt(testData);
        System.out.println("Encrypted data: "+enc);
        String dec = decrypt(enc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted data: "+enc);
    }
    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception 
    {

        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception 
    {
        try{
            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
            byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
            String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
            return decryptedValue;
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Something wrong..");
            return "";
        }
    }
    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception
    {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }
}
```

And I got the Result like:

Encrypted data: `/ia3VXrqaaUls7fon4RBhQ==`

Decrypted data: `ABC`.

Comment: The equals sign at the end is a valid character for Base64 encoding, which you are explicitly doing in your code.  As a general rule, your code should be able to handle any type of String, regardless of content.

Comment: Specifically, it's padding for when you don't have a multiple of three bytes as input.

Comment: I fail to understand why the obfuscated String should be an issue for further processing. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Juxhin - After Encryption I am splitting those data by "string".split("=") for    further processing on those data. Because of that it causes the problem, I am not splitting Encrypted data only, but also non Encrypted data. But Encrypted data also goes from this splitting process.

Comment: Prior to encrypting the data you may hard-change '=' to another special character (be sure to take care of this change when decrypting as well). However I would not recommend this if you need a clean looking algorithm (this is merely a cheap hack that makes the code look clunky) but my be a temporary solution till you figure out a better way to handle it.

Comment: @PrakashHolkar If you want to use send the data through HTTP requests are you handle the parameter splitting yourself, then don't. Use a framework which handles this correctly even with the `=` character. If you still don't want the `=` "special" character, use some other encoding, like Base 58, Base 32 or Hex (Base 16).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Please check my answer, I think base64url is a better alternative.

Answer (score 6):

URL-safe base 64 [as defined in RFC 4648 section-5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) could be used.

To use URL-safe base 64 it is possible to use [the new `Base64` class in `java.util`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#url) (since Java 8). If the `=` must be avoided then it is possible to specify to not use padding. The decoder should of course be configured in the same way:

```
Encoder urlEncoder = java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding();
String encoded = urlEncoder.encodeToString(new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xE0});
System.out.println(encoded);

Decoder urlDecoder = java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder();
byte[] decoded = urlDecoder.decode(encoded);
System.out.printf("(byte) 0x%02X, (byte) 0x%02X%n", decoded[0], decoded[1]);
```

results in:

```
_-A
(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xE0
```

---

Note that it is probably not OK to use base 64 and simply remove the padding. In that case `+` and `/` characters may be returned depending on the input.

Since the output of many cryptographic primitives - especially those used for encryption - is indistinguishable from random, it is possible to get these characters at any time, even for the same plaintext.

This is also why URL encoding the result is a less optimal solution; you don't know how many characters need to be escaped in advance making the output size unpredictable.

Comment: Base64 deals with characters in groups of four.  It is possible for the sending side to remove the trailing '=' characters and for the receiving side to reinsert them before decoding from Base64.  Add as many as needed to make the string length a multiple of four.

Comment: The Java 8 solution works regardless of the padding characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString to make it url safe, which also removes '='

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting into `base64 encoding` use `HEX encoding`. That worked fine for me